# Vuetify - First keypress event value is always an empty string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want the user to not be able to insert a number bigger than 100.

The below excerpt is a simplified production code.
For some reason which I do not yet understand is that the first keypress always returns an empty string.

If you would type `101` in the input, the `event.target.value` value will be `01`.

How can I fix this?

```
<v-text-field
    type="number"
    @keypress="formatNumber($event)"
>
</v-text-field>

formatNumber(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value); // first keypress returns empty string

    if (event.target.value  > 100) {
        event.target.value = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `keypress` to `keyup`

Answer (score 1):

Changing `keypress` to `keyup` calls the function correctly

Comment: I've tried this and there is one caveat.

The inserted value will reappear after you lose the focus of the input.
i.e you type 101, select another input, and the value 101 will reappear on the previous input.

Comment: @Carol-TheodorPelu can you use v-model?

Comment: I can use `v-model`. What would be the approach in this case?

Comment: if `v-model="someVar"` then from function set `this.someVar = null` instead of the `event.target.value`

Comment: that works but I still wonder why the first keypress event value is an empty string.